# Re-mapping Json attribute using a POJO

Tags: java, json, pojo

I have a POJO:

SampleDto.java

```
@Data
public class SampleDto{
  private String A;
  private String B;
  private String C;
  @JsonProperty("E")
  private String D;
}
```

I am mapping this data:

```
{A: 1, B: 2, C: 3, E: 4}
```

When i print out the pojo in terminal, i see:

```
SampleDto(A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4)
```

But when I use postman to print it out, i see this:

```
[
  {
    "A": 1,
    "B": 2,
    "C": 3,
    "E": 4
  }
]
```

How come there is a discrepancy between the postman output and the terminal output?

I would want my postman output to reflect as :

```
    [
      {
        "A": 1,
        "B": 2,
        "C": 3,
        "D": 4
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Remove the `@JsonProperty("E")` from the pojo

Comment: And what would that help me accomplish? That would cause me to see "D": null, and i do not want that. I want to map the "E" into "D" and display it as "D"

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are seeing here is likely because you are misunderstanding serialization vs stringifying.

Whenever you print an Object in Java, it will attempt to call the toString method on that object. That is if you're using System.out.printX(...).

Whereas your @Property annotation is likely fed to some serializer/mapper along the way and it generates JSON. Likely jackson and an ObjectMapper.

This behaviour is normal and makes sense because the standard print method is not aware of such annotations like @Property. If it is required that this POJO does replace "D" with "E", then you could override the toString method on your object.

Comment: I am doing the mapping in bodyToFlux(SampleDto.class), so correct me if I am wrong, but wouldnt the values be attached to the attributes and as such when you return the Flux<SampleDto> back, it should use the attributes of SampleDto.java?